# Wifi not working on Toshiba Satillite s55 with ubuntu 13.04

Tags: wireless, toshiba

I'm new to ubuntu and I'm in trouble. I just installed ubuntu 13.04 on my Toshiba Satillite s55-a5276 and the wifi is not working, it's not giving me an option to search to wifi connection. I have been searching the web for solutions but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please specify your wifi-card model?

If you don't know how just type into terminal `lspci -v | grep -i wireless`

Comment: Done that but can't see any model type for my wifi card.

Comment: This is what I get in the terminal

Comment: Usage: lspci [<switches>]

Basic display modes:
-mm  Produce machine-readable output (single -m for an obsolete format)
-t  Show bus tree

Display options:
-v  Be verbose (-vv for very verbose)
-k  Show kernel drivers handling each device
-x  Show hex-dump of the standard part of the config space
-xxx  Show hex-dump of the whole config space (dangerous; root only)
-xxxx  Show hex-dump of the 4096-byte extended config space (root only)
-b  Bus-centric view (addresses and IRQ's as seen by the bus)
-D  Always show domain numbers

Comment: Resolving of device ID's to names:
-n  Show numeric ID's
-nn  Show both textual and numeric ID's (names & numbers)
-q  Query the PCI ID database for unknown ID's via DNS
-qq  As above, but re-query locally cached entries
-Q  Query the PCI ID database for all ID's via DNS

Selection of devices:
-s [[[[<domain>]:]<bus>]:][<slot>][.[<func>]] Show only devices in selected slots
-d [<vendor>]:[<device>]   Show only devices with specified ID's

Comment: Other options:
-i <file> Use specified ID database instead of wireless
-p <file> Look up kernel modules in a given file instead of default modules.pcimap
-M  Enable `bus mapping' mode (dangerous; root only)

PCI access options:
-A <method> Use the specified PCI access method (see `-A help' for a list)
-O <par>=<val> Set PCI access parameter (see `-O help' for a list)
-G  Enable PCI access debugging
-H <mode> Use direct hardware access (<mode> = 1 or 2)
-F <file> Read PCI configuration dump from a given file

Comment: So strange, I think you can mistyping your command. Please speify command you type.

Comment: I tried lshw -C network and it only shows me the ethernet interface not the wifi card, it's like it can't find my wifi card.

Comment: Could it be Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8179?

Comment: I think I found the solution, thanks a bunch, you really helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the driver for the wireless module was dropped.  I solved the issue on my Satellite S55t-A5238 by upgrading the kernel to 3.10.0:

http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=142420#p754195

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem.  I bought Toshiba Satellite S55 from costco and installed Ubuntu 13.04 first which WIFI doesn't even recognized.  And I updated the OS to 13.10 hoping that it would resolve the issue.  But no luck.  And I read somewhere in the forum saying that I need to download RTL8188EE driver from www.realtek.com for linux flavour the latest one which released on feb/2013.  I have downloaded and followed the instructions.

1. download the driver from (http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/...oads=true#2722)
2. run the following using sodu
   sudo make
   sudo make install
   sudo reboot
3. if not, run the install from combat/script
4. reboot
5. check the wifi using iwlist scan or iwconfig

Comment: The link doesnt work and item 3 doesnt make sense.  Please can you fix these?